# What is qemu-img consistency check?

Tags: qemu, hashsum

I would be glad if someone could explain the meaning of `qemu-img check <filename>` command. Man pages provide very poor information about it:

> ```
>    check [-f fmt] [-r [leaks | all]] filename
>        Perform a consistency check on the disk image filename.
>        If "-r" is specified, qemu-img tries to repair any inconsistencies
>        found during the check. "-r leaks" repairs only cluster leaks,
>        whereas "-r all" fixes all kinds of errors, with a higher risk of
>        choosing the wrong fix or hiding corruption that has already
>        occurred.
>        Only the formats "qcow2", "qed" and "vdi" support consistency
>        checks.
> ```

For instance, can I use this command in case of need to check the hash sum of the disk image (rather hash sums of the files stored on them)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is like a check disk on a physical file that constitute your virtual disk.

See the part:  *Only the formats "qcow2", "qed" and "vdi"*

This mean that your virtual disk can be corrupted, wrong byte or missing data somewhere etc. Those formats seem to support some kind of checking and error correction, and that's the purpose of the option `qemu-img check`

[Wiki](http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/Qcow3) for `qccow2` shows consistency features for example